# Link to a `ref` in another component in React

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I have a footer component in my React app which contains links to different sections of the website.

Instead of lots of different components to render for each section, I am just making a main component for each section and then within this component there are different parts of the page. i.e

```
First page
    section 1
    section 2
    section 3
```

If I want to be able to click a link on the footer to take me to section 3 of the first page, is this possible? Currently I wrote the code in the footer to take me to a new route,

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
      <Typography variant='h6'>Golf</Typography>
      <List>
           <ListItem component={NavLink} color='text.secondary' to='/section-1' sx={{textDecoration:'none', color: 'black'}}>Section 2</ListItem>
           <ListItem component={NavLink}  color='text.secondary' to='/section-2' sx={{textDecoration:'none', color: 'black'}}>Section 2</ListItem>
      </List>
</Grid>
```

But now I want it to take me to a route '/firstpage' and then to section 1 on that page.

On each page I have all the sections wrapped in a div with a `ref` and using the useRef hook

```
const section1 = useRef(null);
const section2 = useRef(null);

const scrollToSection = (elementRef: any) => {
     window.scrollTo({
         top: elementRef.current.offsetTop - 110,
         behavior: 'smooth'
     })
 }

return (

<>
    <div ref={section1}>
      //code
    </div>
    <div ref={section2}>
      //code
    </div>
</>
)
```

On each page I have a basic nav system at the top so when I click on a link it scrolls to the relevant section using the `scrollToSection` function `onClick={() => scrollToSection(section2)}`

Can I use what I already have to be able to let a user click on a link in the footer and it will take them to the correct route and then automatically scroll to that section.